# R: How can I group rows in a dataframe, ID rows meeting a condition, then delete prior rows for the group?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, delete-row

I have a dataframe of customers (identified by ID number), the number of units of two products they bought in each of four years, and a final column identifying the year in which new customers first purchased (the 'key' column). The problem: the dataframe includes rows from the years prior to new customers purchasing for the first time. I need to delete these rows. For example, this dataframe:

```
   customer year item.A item.B  key
1         1 2000     NA     NA         <NA>
2         1 2001     NA     NA         <NA>
3         1 2002      1      5 new.customer
4         1 2003      2      6         <NA>
5         2 2000     NA     NA         <NA>
6         2 2001     NA     NA         <NA>
7         2 2002     NA     NA         <NA>
8         2 2003      2      7 new.customer
9         3 2000      2      4         <NA>
10        3 2001      6      4         <NA>
11        3 2002      2      5         <NA>
12        3 2003      1      8         <NA>
```

needs to look like this:

```
  customer year item.A item.B key
1        1 2002      1      5 new.customer
2        1 2003      2      6         <NA>
3        2 2003      2      7 new.customer
4        3 2000      2      4         <NA>
5        3 2001      6      4         <NA>
6        3 2002      2      5         <NA>
7        3 2003      1      8         <NA>
```

I thought I could do this using dplyr/tidyr - a combination of group, lead/lag, and slice (or perhaps filter and drop_na) but I can't figure out how to delete backwards in the customer group once I've identified the rows meeting the condition "key"=="new.customer". Thanks for any suggestions (code for the full dataframe below).

```
a<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
b<-c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2000,2001,2002,2003,2000,2001,2002,2003)
c<-c(NA,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA,2,2,6,2,1)
d<-c(NA,NA,5,6,NA,NA,NA,7,4,4,5,8)
e<-c(NA,NA,"new",NA,NA,NA,NA,"new",NA,NA,NA,NA) 
df <- data.frame("customer" =a, "year" = b, "C" = c, "D" = d,"key"=e)
df
```

Comment: shouldn't first row of customer 3 be marked as new customer?

Comment: Do these lines necessarily correspond to `NA` for both items and the key? From your (simplified) example, it is the case, but I cannot assume it's true for the entire `data.frame`. If it is, simply: `df[!(is.na(df$C) & is.na(df$D) & is.na(df$key)), ]`, or using `subset` which might be easier to read: `subset(df, !(is.na(C) & is.na(D) & is.na(key)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step I am marking existing customers (customer 3 in this case) in the key column -

```
df %>% 
  group_by(customer) %>% 
  mutate(
    key = as.character(key), # can be avoided if key is a character to begin with
    key = ifelse(row_number() == 1 & (!is.na(C) | !is.na(D)), "existing", key)
  ) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(!is.na(key)) > 0) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 x 5
  customer  year     C     D key     
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1        1  2002     1     5 new     
2        1  2003     2     6 NA      
3        2  2003     2     7 new     
4        3  2000     2     4 existing
5        3  2001     6     4 NA      
6        3  2002     2     5 NA      
7        3  2003     1     8 NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, existing customers have no notation in the ‘key’ column. Maybe the df could be split into two dfs - one for new customers and one for the original esting ones - and your solution appliedto the one for new customers? I could then put them back together.

Comment: @EmilioM.Bruna You don't need to do all that. Just make sure the first row for existing customers is not `NA`. You could populate it with say "existing" instead of `NA`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, though I’d have to backfill the first row for 7k customers. I’m not sure which is simpler.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include logic for existing customers. You don't need to do anything now.